# Proving that $1/x$ and $1/x^2$ limit does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality, proof-verification

1) If I am to prove that limit of $ \frac1x$ doesn't exist at $x\to0$ is it sufficient and rigorous enough to show that the left hand and the right hand limits are not equal(EDIT: are not equal NUMERICALLY) ? Or should I approach it by contradiction to be "RIGOROUS" enough ?

2) Also can someone please explain why Apostol chose $0<x<\frac1{A+2}$ ? I can understand that he made $x>0$ because it is a right hand limits so $x$ should be greater than $0$. Right ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apostol could have written it as

"In the interval $0\lt x\lt 1/(A+1)$, we have $f(x)=1/x^2\gt(A+1)^2\ge
A+1$, so $f(x)$ cannot lie in the neighborhood $N_1(A)$."

Possibly he wanted to stick to strict inequalities.

On a separate quibble, is Apostol being completely rigorous when he writes "say $A\ge0$"?  Don't you need an argument to exclude the possibility of a negative limit?  Or maybe just something like

"In the interval $0\lt x\lt 1/(|A|+1)$, we have $f(x)=1/x^2\gt(|A|+1)^2\ge
A+1$, so $f(x)$ cannot lie in the neighborhood $N_1(A)$."

**Added later**:  I initially thought the OP was asking why Apostol chose to use a $2$ when setting up the interval $0\lt x\lt 1/(A+2)$, but I see from the follow-up questions in comments that the question really goes to the underlying logic of the proof, so I'll try to address that here.

First, where Apostol talks about "a neighborhood $N_1(A)$ of length $1$," I think he meant to write "radius" rather than "length."  But whether you take $\epsilon={1\over2}$ or $\epsilon=1$, you wind up concluding that $f(x)\gt A+\epsilon$ for all $0\lt x\lt 1/(A+2)$ (assuming here, as Apostol does, that $A\ge0$), and hence $f(x)$ is outside $N_1(A)$ for all $x\in(0,{1\over A+2})$. But here's the point:  No matter what you choose for $\delta$, the positive portion of the neighborhood $N_2(0)$, namely $(0,\delta)$, has non-empty intersection with  $(0,{1\over A+2})$.  Thus for *every* $\delta$ there exist points $x\gt0$ in $N_2(0)$ such that $f(x)\not\in N_1(A)$.  So yes, $1\over A+2$ represents only one region, but it's a region that contains points from every region $\delta$, and that's what you need.

Comment: Why did Apostol chose $\delta = \frac1{A+1}$ isn't it incorrect to chose a $\delta$ first then an $\epsilon$ ? I cant see how $\epsilon = 0.5$ is related to the $\delta$. To be more clear: How is the $x < \frac1{A+1}$ related to the $N_1(A)=1$.

Comment: @user2466887, Apostol is *not* choosing any specific $\delta$.  The pertinent reference to $\delta$ occurs in the next sentence, "Thus, *every* neighborhood $N(0)$ contains points $x\gt0$ for which $f(x)$ is outside $N_1(A)$."  (Actually I think he omits a subscript here; elsewhere he consistently writes $N_2(p)$ for the $\delta$ neighborhood around a point $p$.)  To show that a given number is *not* a limit, you need to show that there *is* an epsilon such that for *all* deltas there exist points within the delta neighborhood of $p$ for which $f(x)$ is not within epsilon of the given number.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why he chose $x< \frac1{A+2}$ ? I understand that you have to find a "$\epsilon$ for which all choices of $\delta$ fail to make the f(x) lie in the $\epsilon$". But doesn't $\frac1{A+2}$ represent only one region not every region $\delta$ ?

Comment: @user2466887, I just added some material which I hope answers your question.

Comment: @user2466887, I'm sorry, but I don't understand your last round of questions, partly because they don't make sense grammatically.  I'm not sure what you mean by "a smaller interval than in the region of ${1\over A+2}$."    Also, when you say "it is an empty intersection," what do you mean by "it"?

Comment: Sorry for the bad wording(ignore my previous comment). In your edited post did you mean that since any interval greater than $\frac1{A+2}$ interval will contain $\frac1{A+2}$, also if the interval was smaller $f(x)$ will be greater than $A+1$ so the limit in both cases doesn't exist. That is what you mean right ? Also, can you read the first part of my question and answer it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the disagreement in 1-sided limits causes the 2-sided one not to exist.

Apostol needed any number $x > A+1$. He picked $A+2$.

Comment: Can you please explain why he needed a number x> A+1 ? I thought that for the $\epsilon$ he chose there exists a certain $\delta$. So you cant just randomly pick a $\delta$ ?